# Story featuring spaceship Sleipnir

Tags: story-identification

This story involves a female crew member who ends up outside the ship,  dead, and is horribly distorted,  possibly by a black hole. The name of the vessel is the Sleipnir.

Answer (score 8):

Could this be [The Shadow of Space](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?54230) by Philip José Farmer? It was originally [published in If Magazine](https://archive.org/stream/1967-11_IF#page/n57/mode/2up) in 1967 but has been *repeatedly* anthologised since.

> *Grettir and crew soon find out that the Sleipnir’s final recorded
> speed was 300,000 times the speed of light. They passed out of the
> universe into a grey area, devoid of stars, but filled with large
> spheres.*
>
> *Close by is a particularly large sphere which dwarfs them. About this
> sphere orbits a much smaller sphere and **the gargantuan body of Mrs.
> Wellington! The Sleipnir has also been enlarged and bloated from its
> normal slim lines to a large spindle shape.***
>
> *Grettir is informed that **the Sleipnir** emerged from the smaller sphere.
> Soon they realize that the smaller sphere is their universe. The
> larger sphere and all the other spheres are separate universes.*
>
> <sup><sub>[Orion Press Book Review](http://www.orionpressfanzines.com/articles/shadow_of_space.htm)</sub></sup>